# Why are material UI components not rendered in jsdom when using Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, next.js, material-ui

I am using Jest/React Testing Library to test the UI.

I have a component whose return statement looks like this:

```
const sidebarContentUp = (
    <Drawer
      anchor="left"
      onClose={onMobileClose}
      open={openMobile}
      PaperProps={{
        sx: {
          backgroundColor: 'background.paper',
          width: 280,
        },
      }}
      variant="temporary"
      data-testid="drawer-up"
    >
      {content}
    </Drawer>
  );

  const sidebarContentDown = (
    <Drawer
      anchor="left"
      open
      PaperProps={{
        sx: {
          backgroundColor: 'background.paper',
          height: 'calc(100% - 64px) !important',
          top: '64px !Important',
          width: 280,
        },
      }}
      variant="persistent"
    >
      {content}
    </Drawer>
  );

  return (
    <>
      {process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_IS_TESTING ? (
        <Grid>
          <div>div2</div>
          {sidebarContentUp}
          {/* {sidebarContentDown} */}
          <div>div3</div>
        </Grid>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Hidden lgUp>{sidebarContentUp}</Hidden>
          <Hidden lgDown>{sidebarContentDown}</Hidden>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

There are no hidden attributes or anything for `sidebarContentUp`, but it is never rendered in the jsdom when running tests.

I only see div2 and div3

I could not figure out for days.

Why is it not rendered, and how can I fix this?

Another issue that might give more hints is that when I don't have `{sidebarContentDown}` commented out, it throws an error

```
 Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined]
```

Comment: I think you can't see the Drawer because it's closed, the prop openMobile is false, try to change it to true.

Comment: did you figure it out? I'm having also some issues with MUI in tests

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `container` element returned by the `render` function, stop using it and use `baseElement` instead. MUI drawers are attached to the `body` so `container` won't include the contents of your drawers.

This should work:

```
const { baseElement } = render();
expect(baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
```

This souldn't work:

```
const { container } = render();
expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
```